# The set of all open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ and the sets of the form $(a,b)\setminus(A\cap(a,b))$ is a basis for some topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I have to do this exercise where we let $A=\{\frac{1}{n}\mid  n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathbb{R}$. We let $\mathcal{B}$ of all open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ together with the sets of the form $(a,b)\setminus(A\cap(a,b))$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b$. We need to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for some topology on $\mathbb{R}$. We let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$, and denote by $X$ the topological space obtained from equipping $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathcal{T}$. Prove that $X$ is Hausdorff.

To show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for some topology on $\mathbb{R}$ I am thinking I have to show that for each $x\in X$ there is at least one basis element B in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B$, and that for $B',B''\in\mathcal{B}$ and $x\in B'\cap B''$ there is a $B'''\subseteq B'\cap B''$ such that $x\in B'''$. I am thinking I have to define a $B\in \mathcal{B}$, such that $x\in B$ for any $x\in X$. I am thinking that I can define $B=(a,b)$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b$, or should I probably choose a specific a and b $\mathbb{R}$, if that's the case, I can't figure out which a and b would do the job. I am generally confused about hos to find this B, and how to find these $B''', B'$ and $B''$.

Furthermore to show that X is Hausdorff, I am thinking I have to show that for all distinct points $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists neighborhoods U and V of x and y respectively such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$, but I am confused about how to do so as well.

Comment: Those are the definitions, yes.

Comment: Yes I know that those are the definitions, that's I want to use them to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, and X is Hausdorff? What exactly is your point?

Comment: It’s just the topology where we take the subbase of all open intervals plus $A^\complement$. The generated base is exactly $\mathcal B$. And as it’s finer than the usual topology it’s trivially Hausdorff.

Comment: How can I show that it is the topology where we take the sublease of all open intervals plus $A^{\complement}$, and how can I show that the generated base is exactly $\mathcal{B}$?. I can see that it's finer than the usual topology, but how can I show that if a topology is Hausdorff, then a topology which is finer than that topology is Hausdorff as well?

Comment: In the same class as [Sara](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/830854/sara), I gather? Check the answers and questions by that user too...

Comment: You can already find disjoint intervals. You can use them.

Comment: okay that makes sense, then I am just confused about how I can show that the usual topology is Hausdorff?